# Bulk insert unable to access file on network

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a c sharp application in one server and sql server database on different server. When I try to run bulk insert through C Sharp application, I am getting

> "Cannot bulk load because the file operating system error code 5
>   (Access is denied)"

When i tried the same in sql server on the database server manually, it worked for windows authentication but not for sql authentication.

What should I do in order to make sql authentication work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server uses security profile of SQL Server service account to access the file if SQL Server authentication was used. OTOH with windows authenticatin, the authenticated windows account must have acces to the file. That's why it worked for you in one case and not in the other one. Give SQL Server service account access to the file.

The other point here is delegation. See this article for the explanation (and a remedy):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/10/29/sql-bulk-copy-error-operating-system-error-code-5-access-is-denied.aspx

Comment: how to give SQL Server Service account access to the file??

Comment: Use Windows explorer to access the folder and configure access from security tab of properties page. The account the SQL Server is running under can be found in configuration manager or services applet.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, use SQL Server Authentication and specify a SQL Server login that uses the security profile of the SQL Server process account, or configure Windows to enable security account delegation.

Plese go through these references also [BulkInsert](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)  ,[SecurityAccountDelegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa905162)

Hope this will help.